# Attempting Pivot Table, how to resolve "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index "

Tags: pandas

I was just trying to make a simple function for pivot table.
But the error **"If using all scalar values, you must pass an index "** came out using dataframe named 'log'

I've searched that various cases of this error were from dictionary. 
Please somebody give me any advises, it'll help me a lot :)

```
import pandas as pd

def find_log(user_id = None , columns = None, viewid = None):

    table = pd.pivot_table(log, index = user_id, columns = columns)

    return table

log.apply(find_log)
```

samples of data 'log'[image]

Comment: would you please share a few columns of your data?

Comment: Please post a sample of your data.

Comment: Thank you! I just added sample